# Android Rendering multi locale fonts using fontFamily

Tags: android, android-fonts

- I have an app that uses two languages (Locales) and I want to set a different font for different languages, I have created two folders in my res directory `font` and `font-ar`, when I change locale configuration in-app programmatically from English to Arabic and start an Intent from my launcher Activity app still shows in English font, my resources `strings.xml`, `drawable.xml` are getting updated as per the Locale but the font is not getting updated.
- But when I kill my app and restart the application then fonts are reflected in Arabic

Please find my font directory
[image]

//Setting my font like this in my layout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/offer_name_tv"
    android:fontFamily="@font/muli_bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_lsmall"
    android:maxWidth="230dp"
    android:text="Mall of Emirates Mall of Emirates Mall of Emirates"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_lllmedium"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

```
public static void changeToArabicLanguage(Context context) {

        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(new Locale("ar"));
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(new Locale("ar"));
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

calling like this from my Fragment to change language

```
Utility.changeToArabicLanguage(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SplashScreenActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```